# The request time on the server is not synchronized with the time submitted to the client

Tags: javascript, laravel, datetime, timer

I want to send a request to the server at a certain time of the day. The time now is GMT +1. Time is GMT +7 local side. I converted the server time to local time and used javascript to set an interval to count down time. The code I mentioned at the bottom.

    var endMilisecond = '1512831599100';
    var timer;

```
function showRemaining() {
    var nowMilisecond = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = endMilisecond - nowMilisecond;
    if (distance <= 0) {
        //Call Ajax send request to server here
        clearInterval(timer);
        return;
    }
}
timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 100);
```

I want the time I sent the request to the server and the time server receive requests is equal.

But Server request delay time is a few seconds

Comment: I'm not really sure your problem is related to the code. You send a request to the server across the globe and expecting there is no delay just as you working on your local?

Comment: Right. I don't know where the delay is

Comment: Put `date_default_timezone_set('YourTimeZone');` in AppServiceProvider.php boot methode.